# How can I get Mathematica to produce better Fortran code?

Tags: fortran, code-organization

I am new to *Mathematica*  and I am trying to get to it to produce some expressions in Fortran code. However, it seems that *Mathematica* will output duplicated expressions, that is, expressions the need not be calculated more than once. Is there any good method to define a rule so that *Mathematica*  will recognize duplicated expressions, assign them to a new variable, and then optimize the Fortran code?

P.S:

The following is some code I wrote to test *Mathematica*'s Fortran capabilities.  The solution of x, y and z contains many duplicated expressions, for example, (-36*a + 20*a**3 - 216*b)**2.

```
sol = Solve[{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, x + y + z == a , x*y*z == b}, {x, y, z}];
xx = x /. sol
yy = y /. sol
zz = z /. sol
Print["Writing Fortran Code . . . : / "];
SetDirectory["F:\\tang\\mathtest"];
strm = OpenWrite["test.f90", FormatType -> FotranForm,  PageWidth -> 70];
(* write subroutine of invisopar*)
WriteString[strm, "subroutine test(x,y,z,a,b)\n"];
WriteString[strm, "implicit none\n"];
WriteString[strm, "real*8::x,y,z,a,b\n"];
nroot = Length[xx];
For[ii = 1, ii <= nroot,
  WriteString[strm,
   "x = " <> ToString[FortranForm[xx[[ii]]]] <> "\n"]; ii++];

For[ii = 1, ii <= nroot,
  WriteString[strm,
   "y = " <> ToString[FortranForm[yy[[ii]]]] <> "\n"]; ii++];

For[ii = 1, ii <= nroot,
  WriteString[strm,
   "z = " <> ToString[FortranForm[zz[[ii]]]] <> "\n"]; ii++];

WriteString[strm, "end subroutine\n"];
Close[strm];
Print["Finished Writing Fortran Code . . . : / "];
```

When the test.f90 is outputted, the first solution of x is:

> x = a/3. + (-6 + 2*a**2)/(3.*2**0.6666666666666666*(-36*a + 20*a**3 +
>   Sqrt(4*(-6 + 2*a**2)**3 + (-36*a + 20*a**3 - 216*b)**2) -
>   216*b)**0.3333333333333333) - (-36*a + 20*a**3 + Sqrt(4*(-6 +
>   2*a**2)**3 + (-36*a + 20*a**3 - 216*b)**2) -
>   216*b)**0.3333333333333333/(6.*2**0.3333333333333333)

I would like that the code is as follows:

```
tmp0 = 216*b
tmp1 = -36*a + 20*a**3
tmp2 = (tmp1 - tmp0 )**2
tmp3 = -6 + 2*a**2
tmp4 = 4*tmp3**3
tmp5 = Sqrt(tmp4 + tmp2 )
tmp6 = tmp1 + tmp5 - tmp0
tmp7 = tmp6**0.3333333333333333
tmp8 = 2**0.6666666666666666
x = a/3. + tmp3 /(3.*tmp8 *tmp7 ) - tmp7/(6.*tmp8)
```

I noticed that maple has the capability for optimizing Fortran; for example, the following maple code can output optimized Fortran code:

```
with(codegen, fortran)
A := array(1 .. 2, 1 .. 2, symmetric); 
A[1, 1] := log(x); A[1, 2] := 1-log(x); A[2, 2] := 2-log(x);
print(A);
fortran(A, optimized, mode = double)
```

So I want to know whether *Mathematica*  also can do similar optimization.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but a couple of things that might help are [HornerForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HornerForm.html) for polynomials and the OptimizeExpression code used by [Compile](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html). For the latter, see [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/821) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057905) and linked questions.

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you very much for your comment. Could you please give me more detailed information about OptimizeExpression? I checked the help and only find the C code example. Thanks, Tang Laoya

Comment: @user58211 I've written up a quick example. Also, can you edit your profile so that it displays your name/alias? People are often more willing to help you if you're more than just a number!

Comment: Did you really write `FormatType -> FotranForm` in your code?  That's not gonna work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

OK, here's a quick go using `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression ``, which is used internally by `Compile`. I'm not claiming that this is a polished solution to your problem, but hopefully it can be used as a place to start.
(Also, forgive any Fortran mistakes, I haven't looked at Fortran for a long time...)

```
xx = x /. Solve[{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, x + y + z == a, x*y*z == b}, {x, y, z}] // First;

Quiet[Remove["tmp*"]]  (* otherwise the numbers after 'tmp' keep going up *)
Module[{out}, 
  out = Experimental`OptimizeExpression[xx, "OptimizationSymbol" -> tmp] /. 
    HoldPattern[Experimental`OptimizedExpression[Block[{tempVars__}, 
      CompoundExpression[defs : Set[_, _] ..., expr_]]]] :> Block[{
        Set = ToString[#1] <> " = " <> ToString[FortranForm[#2]] &}, List[defs, expr]];
{"subroutine test(x,a,b)", "implicit none", "real*8::x,a,b",
 Most@out, "x = " <> ToString@FortranForm@N@Last@out, 
 "end subroutine"}
] // Flatten // ExportString[#, "Table"] &
```

> ```
> subroutine test(x,a,b)
> implicit none
> real*8::x,a,b
> tmp4 = a**2
> tmp5 = 2*tmp4
> tmp6 = -6 + tmp5
> tmp7 = -36*a
> tmp8 = a**3
> tmp9 = 20*tmp8
> tmp12 = -216*b
> tmp10 = tmp6**3
> tmp11 = 4*tmp10
> tmp13 = tmp12 + tmp7 + tmp9
> tmp14 = tmp13**2
> tmp15 = tmp11 + tmp14
> tmp16 = Sqrt(tmp15)
> tmp17 = tmp12 + tmp16 + tmp7 + tmp9
> x = 0.3333333333333333*a - 0.13228342099734997*tmp17**0.3333333333333333 + \
>     (0.20998684164914552*tmp6)/tmp17**0.3333333333333333
> end subroutine
> ```

This can easily be modified to process and output more than just the first solution for `x` and can also be made to export to a file instead of a string.
It's not as compact as hand code would make it, some of the `tmp` definitions, I would join together, but it's not bad.
Also, note that the other solutions for `x` contain complex numbers and might have to be treated a little more carefully.

Comment: Dear all,

Since x have 6 roots, how to let it output all these roots to Fortran code, such as 
x(1)=...
x(2)=...
...

Thanks

Comment: Furthermore, I'd like to output the Fortran code to a file, by the For loop, how to do?

Comment: @Simon, how can we get 1.0d0 real*8 value in MMA??? thanks in advance!

Comment: @Simon, your solution will also work with `CForm`. Is there any way to make these `tmp**` as `Array`  for `Fortran` or for `C`?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use MathCode?

MathCode makes it possible to develop prototypes in the interactive *Mathematica* environment which can be automatically translated to fast production code in C++ or Fortran90 and, if necessary, linked to external applications.

Comment: ……Because it's [not free](https://store.wolfram.com/view/app/mathcodef90/)?

Comment: @xzczd and Mathematica is free?

Comment: Come on, not every one can spend another $2,495.00 without hesitation. BTW, the discount of _MathCode_ for students is really stingy compared to _Mathematica_: _Mathematica_ student version only sells for 140 dollars (50.00 dollars in China, at least when I bought it), while _MathCode_ sells for $1,095.00 even in education store!

Comment: if you are looking for free alternatives, then python code can be transformed into fortran using sympy or into c/c++ using many other open-source libs.