# Find repeated groups in a long algebraic expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an algebraic output (a solution to a de) similar to, but far longer than:

{y->(x+3)^2/sin(7*(x+3))+(x+3)^3/7}

I'd like to get Mathematica to notice that the group x+3 appears repeatedly, define a new parameter par1=x+3, and rewrite the original output as:

{par1=x+3,
par1^2/sin(7*par1)+par1^3/7}

The new expression would be far simpler and faster to evaluate than the original if par1 is, say 40 characters long, and appears say 6 times in the original expression.

Ideas on how to accomplish this?

Eric

Comment: It seems you haven't tried anything. At first instead of `sin(7*(x+3))` there should be `Sin[7*(x+3)]`, then you could try e.g.  `{y -> (x + 3)^2/Sin[7*(x + 3)] + (x + 3)^3/7} /. x + 3 -> par`.

Comment: This seems to solve the same problem [How can I get Mathematica to produce better Fortran code?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17736/how-can-i-get-mathematica-to-produce-better-fortran-code) Edit: Everything here will probably be helpfull: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=OptimizeExpression