# Latest Mathematica 9.0 can't use Format.m to generate optimized Fortran code

Tags: simplifying-expressions, code-generation, fortran

Before updating to *Mathematica* 9.0, I have successfully generated beautiful Fortran code using Mark Sofroniou's `Format.m` package, which is posted [on MathSource](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/60/).

However, after updating to the latest *Mathematica*, version 9.0, the program can't work; the following error displayed when running the code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
<< format`Format`
(* -> Get::noopen: Cannot open format`Format`. >> *)
```

Could anyone tell me how to set up `Format.m` in *Mathematica* 9.0?

Comment: Looks like you simply haven't placed the file in the correct location or are loading it using an incorrect path.

Comment: Hi OleKsandr, thanks for your kindly reply. Where should I put the file? I have put it to the same path of the program I running.

Comment: [The documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaFileOrganization.html) describes how packages should ordinarily be set up. If you don't do it that way, you do at least have to put it in one of the directories on `$Path`, and load it as `Format.m`, not just `Format\``. Alternatively, just load the file using the front end and click the "Run Package" button.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. I tried your last option: just load the file and click the 'Run Package' button, however, the following errors displayed: Get::noopen: Cannot open Utilities`FilterOptions`. >>

Needs::nocont: Context Utilities`FilterOptions` was not created when Needs was evaluated. >>

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compatibility/tutorial/Utilities/FilterOptions.html

Comment: thanks. I have replaced ALL 'FilterOptions' to 'Sequence@@FilterRules' and the Format.m can be run successfully. Then I changed the beginning of my program from

<< format`Format`

to

<< format`Format.m`


the following errors still displayed:


Get::noopen: Cannot open format`Format.m`. >>


How to modify the program?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after I used this file:
https://github.com/Expander/FlexibleSUSY/blob/master/meta/Format.m

and put it to here:
C:\Users\tang\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\format

Thanks

Update:

there is another problem:

```
v = Det[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, {y1, y2, y3, y4}, {z1, z2, 
     z3, z4}}]/6;
b1 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {y2, y3, y4}, {z2, z3, z4}}];
c1 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x2, x3, x4}, {z2, z3, z4}}];
d1 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x2, x3, x4}, {y2, y3, y4}}];
b2 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {y1, y3, y4}, {z1, z3, z4}}];
c2 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x3, x4}, {z1, z3, z4}}];
d2 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x3, x4}, {y1, y3, y4}}];
b3 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {y1, y2, y4}, {z1, z2, z4}}];
c3 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x2, x4}, {z1, z2, z4}}];
d3 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x2, x4}, {y1, y2, y4}}];
b4 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {y1, y2, y3}, {z1, z2, z3}}];
c4 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x2, x3}, {z1, z2, z3}}];
d4 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x2, x3}, {y1, y2, y3}}];
bcdv = {b1, c1, d1, b2, c2, d2, b3, c3, d3, b4, c4, d4, v};
FortranAssign[bcdv, bcdv, OptimizationSymbol -> tmp]
```

It will give the following express:

```
    tmp90=-z3
    tmp93=-z1
    tmp100=-z4
    tmp87=-z2
    bcdv(1)=y3*z2-y4*z2-y2*z3+y4*z3+y2*z4-y3*z4
    bcdv(2)=-(x3*z2)+x4*z2+x2*z3-x4*z3-x2*z4+x3*z4
    bcdv(3)=x3*y2-x4*y2-x2*y3+x4*y3+x2*y4-x3*y4
    bcdv(4)=-(y3*z1)+y4*z1+y1*z3-y4*z3-y1*z4+y3*z4
    bcdv(5)=x3*z1-x4*z1-x1*z3+x4*z3+x1*z4-x3*z4
    bcdv(6)=-(x3*y1)+x4*y1+x1*y3-x4*y3-x1*y4+x3*y4
    bcdv(7)=y2*z1-y4*z1-y1*z2+y4*z2+y1*z4-y2*z4
    bcdv(8)=-(x2*z1)+x4*z1+x1*z2-x4*z2-x1*z4+x2*z4
    bcdv(9)=x2*y1-x4*y1-x1*y2+x4*y2+x1*y4-x2*y4
    bcdv(10)=-(y2*z1)+y3*z1+y1*z2-y3*z2-y1*z3+y2*z3
    bcdv(11)=x2*z1-x3*z1-x1*z2+x3*z2+x1*z3-x2*z3
    bcdv(12)=-(x2*y1)+x3*y1+x1*y2-x3*y2-x1*y3+x2*y3
    bcdv(13)=x4*(y3*(tmp87+z1)+y1*(tmp90+z2)+y2*(tmp93+z3))+x3*(y2*(
 &  tmp100+z1)+y4*(tmp93+z2)+y1*(tmp87+z4))+x1*(y3*(tmp100+z2)+y4*(t
 &  mp87+z3)+y2*(tmp90+z4))+x2*(y4*(tmp90+z1)+y1*(tmp100+z3)+y3*(tmp
 &  93+z4))
```

However, that's not most efficient, the most efficient code is like the following:

```
x1=x(2)-x(1)
y1=y(2)-y(1)
z1=z(2)-z(1)
x2=x(3)-x(2)
y2=y(3)-y(2)
z2=z(3)-z(2)
x3=x(4)-x(3)
y3=y(4)-y(3)
z3=z(4)-z(3)
x4=x(1)-x(4)
y4=y(1)-y(4)
z4=z(1)-z(4)
B1=Y3*Z2-Y2*Z3
B2=Y3*Z4-Y4*Z3
B3=Y1*Z4-Y4*Z1
B4=Y1*Z2-Y2*Z1
C1=X2*Z3-X3*Z2
C2=X4*Z3-X3*Z4
C3=X4*Z1-X1*Z4
C4=X2*Z1-X1*Z2
D1=X3*Y2-X2*Y3
D2=X3*Y4-X4*Y3
D3=X1*Y4-X4*Y1
D4=X1*Y2-X2*Y1
V=(x(1)*b1+x(2)*b2+x(3)*b3+x(4)*b4)/6.0d0
```

So my question is: how to let mathematica generate most efficient Fortran code?

Thanks,
Tang Laoya

Comment: Hello Tang Laoya, I've marked this question as a "simple mistake", since it was mainly about placing it in the correct path (and a minor fix for `FilterOptions`). Regarding the _new question_ you raise in your _answer_, I think this answer: [How can I get Mathematica to produce better Fortran code?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17744) to your previous question is what you're looking for. If I'm mistaken, then please post this as a new question, perhaps also explaining why Simon's answer there doesn't apply here.

Comment: Hi rm, thanks for your process. The old problem is solved by used an updated Format.m and placed it to the correct location. But I have some new problems as I described. I think that they are the same kind of problems so I placed it here. Thanks.