# Output most efficient Fortran code by mathematica

Tags: code-generation, fortran

I am trying to output most efficient Fortran code by mathematica 9.0 with the method Simon provided:
[How can I get Mathematica to produce better Fortran code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17736/how-can-i-get-mathematica-to-produce-better-fortran-code/17744#17744)

The expressions is as follows:

```
v = Det[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, {y1, y2, y3, y4}, {z1, z2, 
     z3, z4}}]/6;
b1 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {y2, y3, y4}, {z2, z3, z4}}];
c1 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x2, x3, x4}, {z2, z3, z4}}];
d1 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x2, x3, x4}, {y2, y3, y4}}];
b2 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {y1, y3, y4}, {z1, z3, z4}}];
c2 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x3, x4}, {z1, z3, z4}}];
d2 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x3, x4}, {y1, y3, y4}}];
b3 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {y1, y2, y4}, {z1, z2, z4}}];
c3 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x2, x4}, {z1, z2, z4}}];
d3 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x2, x4}, {y1, y2, y4}}];
b4 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {y1, y2, y3}, {z1, z2, z3}}];
c4 = -Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x2, x3}, {z1, z2, z3}}];
d4 = Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {x1, x2, x3}, {y1, y2, y3}}];
bcdv = {b1, c1, d1, b2, c2, d2, b3, c3, d3, b4, c4, d4, v};
```

The code to produce Fortran code is as follows:

```
out = Experimental`OptimizeExpression[FullSimplify[bcdv], 
    "OptimizationSymbol" -> tmp] /. 
   HoldPattern[
     Experimental`OptimizedExpression[
      Block[{tempVars__}, 
       CompoundExpression[defs : Set[_, _] ..., expr_]]]] :> 
    Block[{Set = 
       ToString[#1] <> " = " <> ToString[FortranForm[#2]] &}, 
     List[defs, expr]];
out2 = out // Flatten // ExportString[#, "Table"] &
```

However, it produced the following code (with the number of production operations be 69):

```
tmp9 = -z3
tmp6 = -z4
tmp3 = -z2
tmp15 = tmp6 + z3
tmp33 = -z1
tmp10 = tmp9 + z4
tmp26 = -y3
tmp23 = -y4
tmp39 = tmp6 + z1
tmp17 = tmp3 + z4
tmp7 = tmp6 + z2
tmp34 = tmp33 + z4
tmp47 = -y1
tmp20 = -y2
tmp56 = tmp3 + z1
tmp13 = tmp9 + z2
tmp37 = tmp33 + z3
tmp51 = tmp33 + z2
tmp30 = tmp9 + z1
tmp4 = tmp3 + z3
tmp53 = tmp39*y2
tmp10*y2 + tmp7*y3 + tmp4*y4
tmp15*x2 + tmp17*x3 + tmp13*x4
x3*(tmp23 + y2) + x4*(tmp20 + y3) + x2*(tmp26 + y4)
tmp15*y1 + tmp34*y3 + tmp30*y4
tmp10*x1 + tmp39*x3 + tmp37*x4
x4*(tmp26 + y1) + x1*(tmp23 + y3) + x3*(tmp47 + y4)
tmp53 + tmp17*y1 + tmp51*y4
tmp7*x1 + tmp34*x2 + tmp56*x4
x2*(tmp23 + y1) + x4*(tmp47 + y2) + x1*(tmp20 + y4)
tmp13*y1 + tmp37*y2 + tmp56*y3
tmp4*x1 + tmp30*x2 + tmp51*x3
x3*(tmp20 + y1) + x1*(tmp26 + y2) + x2*(tmp47 + y3)
(-(x2*y3*z1) + x2*y4*z1 + x1*y3*z2 - x1*y4*z2 + x2*y1*z3 - x1*y2*z3 + \
x1*y4*z3 - x2*y4*z3 + x4*(-(y2*z1) + y3*z1 + y1*z2 - y3*z2 - y1*z3 + \
y2*z3) + (-(x2*y1) + x1*y2 - x1*y3 + x2*y3)*z4 + x3*(tmp53 - y4*z1 - \
y1*z2 + y4*z2 + y1*z4))/6
```

The ideal code is as follows, with the number of production operations be 29:

```
x1=x(2)-x(1)
y1=y(2)-y(1)
z1=z(2)-z(1)
x2=x(3)-x(2)
y2=y(3)-y(2)
z2=z(3)-z(2)
x3=x(4)-x(3)
y3=y(4)-y(3)
z3=z(4)-z(3)
x4=x(1)-x(4)
y4=y(1)-y(4)
z4=z(1)-z(4)
B1=Y3*Z2-Y2*Z3
B2=Y3*Z4-Y4*Z3
B3=Y1*Z4-Y4*Z1
B4=Y1*Z2-Y2*Z1
C1=X2*Z3-X3*Z2
C2=X4*Z3-X3*Z4
C3=X4*Z1-X1*Z4
C4=X2*Z1-X1*Z2
D1=X3*Y2-X2*Y3
D2=X3*Y4-X4*Y3
D3=X1*Y4-X4*Y1
D4=X1*Y2-X2*Y1
V=(x(1)*b1+x(2)*b2+x(3)*b3+x(4)*b4)/6.0d0
```

Is there any better way to produce high efficient Fortran code?

Thanks,
Tang Laoya