# Generate FORTRAN77 code from Mathematica

Tags: code-generation

I need to transform a function from Mathematica to Fortran77. An internal program FortranForm gives some result, but it works incorrectly in Fortran77. The string must start a 7th column and finish at 72th, ArcTan and Log must be transformed to ATAN and DLOG respectively, numbers also must be transformed (e.g. 2. -> 2d0).

I have a function:

```
 C3 (c - y) + 
 C3 (c + y) + ((1 + nu) (-1 + 2 nu) P (c - y) ArcTan[(-c + y)/
   x])/(π Y) + ((1 + nu) (-1 + 2 nu) P (c + y) ArcTan[(c + y)/
   x])/(π Y) + ((-1 + nu) (1 + nu) P x Log[
   x^2 + (c - y)^2])/(π Y) + ((1 + nu) P (x - nu x) Log[
   x^2 + (c + y)^2])/(π Y)
```

I'd like to have the following result:

```
< V = C3*(c - y) + C3*(c + y) + 
 &  ((1D0 + nu)*(-1D0 + 2D0*nu)*P*(c - y)*ATAN((-c + y)/x))/(Pi*E) + 
 &  ((1D0 + nu)*(-1D0 + 2D0*nu)*P*(c + y)*ATAN((c + y)/x))/(Pi*E) + 
 &  ((-1D0 + nu)*(1D0 + nu)*P*x*DLOG(x**2 + (c - y)**2))/(Pi*E) + 
 &  ((1D0 + nu)*P*(x - nu*x)*DLOG(x**2 + (c + y)**2))/(Pi*E)
>
```

Here I have first string starting from 7-th columns (V=...), symbol & at 6-th position show continuation, 1->1D0, ArcTan->ATAN, Y->E, etc.

Comment: "a function" - where is it?

Comment: Any function, actually. Let's say U = ((1 + nu) (-1 + 2 nu) P x ArcTan[(c - y)/
   x])/(\[Pi] Y) + ((1 + nu) (-1 + 2 nu) P x ArcTan[(c + y)/
   x])/(\[Pi] Y) + ((1 + nu) P (-c + y) (-3 - Log[4] + 
    nu (4 + Log[4])))/(
 2 \[Pi] Y) - ((1 + nu) P (c + y) (-3 - Log[4] + nu (4 + Log[4])))/(
 2 \[Pi] Y) + ((-1 + nu) (1 + nu) P (c - y) Log[
   x^2 + (c - y)^2])/(\[Pi] Y) + ((-1 + nu) (1 + nu) P (c + y) Log[
   x^2 + (c + y)^2])/(\[Pi] Y)

Comment: edit the question with the details.  Why f77? Every fortran compiler in the past 20 years supports f90 at least.  Use freeform and forget about the column 7 issue.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17736/2079

Comment: Only partial translation of expressions is supported, so you will have to implement anything not supported out of the box individually.

Comment: `FortranForm` cannot translate functions.  It can only translate simple expressions, and even then its result is more of a starting point ... I would use `ReplaceAll` on `ArcTan -> ATAN` and would edit the result with a text editor (including fixing numbers).

Comment: @YvesKlett What I don't know is how to do that efficiently using `Format`.  `Format` is assignable.  But do we assign it a string?  Then the quotes are preserved in the output.

Comment: Please add a useful example of input/output to your question to work with. The more specific your question, the higher the chance to get good answers.

Comment: I tied to specify the question. Hope now it is more clear

Comment: FORTRAN77  Code Generation Package
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/60/

Comment: @IgorPy If you try that package, feel free to post an answer to your own question and show how it went!  In fact it would be much appreciated if you could do that together with a short example.  I took a quick look at the package documentation and it appears to be able to handle everything you need. But I don't have time to study it in detail.

Answer (score 9):

**Warning: as @george points out in the comments, something is wrong with the output of this package.  It produced incorrect d0d0.  I don't have time to investigate at the moment, so making it community wiki.  Feel free to post your own (corrected) answer based on the information here.**

Using [the `Format.m` package](http://packagedata.net/index.php/#package-207) that @Orders posted,

```
expr = C3 (c - y) + 
   C3 (c + y) + ((1 + nu) (-1 + 2 nu) P (c - y) ArcTan[(-c + y)/
        x])/(π Y) + ((1 + nu) (-1 + 2 nu) P (c + 
        y) ArcTan[(c + y)/x])/(π Y) + ((-1 + nu) (1 + nu) P x Log[
       x^2 + (c - y)^2])/(π Y) + ((1 + nu) P (x - nu x) Log[
       x^2 + (c + y)^2])/(π Y);

FortranAssign["expr", expr, AssignReplace -> {"log" -> "dlog"}, AssignOptimize -> False]
```

gives the following

```
        expr = C3*(c - y) + C3*(c + y) + (3.183098861837907d-1*(1.d0 + n
     &  u)*(-1.d0d0 + 2.d0*nu)*P*(c - y)*atan((-c + y)/x))/Y + (3.183098
     &  861837907d-1*(1.d0 + nu)*(-1.d0d0 + 2.d0*nu)*P*(c + y)*atan((c +
     &   y)/x))/Y + (3.183098861837907d-1*(-1.d0d0 + nu)*(1.d0 + nu)*P*x
     &  *dlog((c - y)**2 + x*x))/Y + (3.183098861837907d-1*(1.d0 + nu)*P
     &  *(x - nu*x)*dlog((c + y)**2 + x*x))/Y
```

The `3.183d-1` you see here is simply a decimal approximation of `1/Pi` to double precision.

We can also use automatic expression optimization, which changes the formula to an equivalent form that minimizes the number of arithmetic operations.  For this it needs to use temporary variables, which I named `tempXX` here.

```
FortranAssign["expr", expr, AssignReplace -> {"log" -> "dlog"}, 
 "OptimizationSymbol" -> temp]

        temp1 = -y
        temp2 = c + temp1
        temp6 = 1.d0 + nu
        temp7 = 2.d0*nu
        temp8 = -1.d0d0 + temp7
        temp4 = c + y
        temp9 = 1/Y
        temp10 = 1/x
        temp20 = x*x
        expr = C3*temp2 + C3*temp4 + 3.183098861837907d-1*P*temp4*temp6*
     &  temp8*temp9*atan(temp10*temp4) + 3.183098861837907d-1*P*temp2*te
     &  mp6*temp8*temp9*atan(temp10*(-c + y)) + 3.183098861837907d-1*(-1
     &  .d0d0 + nu)*P*temp6*temp9*x*dlog(temp20 + temp2*temp2) + 3.18309
     &  8861837907d-1*P*temp6*temp9*(x - nu*x)*dlog(temp20 + temp4*temp4
     &  )
```

---

Getting the package to work in Mathematca 10:

If you try to load it as is, it will complain about not finding `` Utilities`FilterOptions` ``, a package that no longer ships with Mathematica 10.  To fix this,

- Change `` BeginPackage["Format`", "Utilities`FilterOptions`"] `` to `` BeginPackage["Format`"] ``.
- Add `FilterOptions[fun_, opts___] := Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[fun]]` right after `` Begin["Private`"] ``.

Comment: looks a little buggy, `d0d0` ?

Comment: I use Mathematica 10.3. I've got the package Format.m, changed it using instructions and installed. However when I try to use a command <&lt;Format.m from this example http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/examples/id/207 , I have a following mistake "Syntax::sntxb: Expression cannot begin with "<&lt". " What can be wrong?

Comment: @IgorPy That should be `<<Format.m`.  However, as you can see, the package misformats negative numbers and gives `-1.d0d0` with a double `d0d0`.  I looked at how to fix this and I came away with the conclusion that it's not worth it.  It depends on internal Mathematica implementation details that are messy and changed since this package was written.  I think you're better off manually editing the output and fixing up problems.  Unless you really need to translate hundreds and hundreds of expressions in which case you can write your own package. Give that at least 1-2 days of time.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks a lot! I will use your package and change d0d0 to d0 manually. Now it works.

Comment: @IgorPy It's not my package ... if it were I would fix it ...