# How to accelerate my code?

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review

Given a 2D $M \times N$ matrix with non-negative values, I would like to find a path going from top to bottom such that the sum of the path is minimum. My function is defined as follow:

```
findSeam[e_List] := Module[{f, t, p, i, j, k, nrows, ncols},

    {nrows, ncols} = Dimensions[e];
    f = Table[0, {i, nrows}, {j, ncols}];
    t = Table[0, {i, nrows}, {j, ncols}];

    For [j = 1, j <= ncols, j++, 
        f[[1, j]] = e[[1, j]];
        t[[1, j]] = 0;
    ];

    For [i = 2, i <= nrows, i++,
        For [j = 1, j <= ncols, j++, 
            If [j == 1, k = j, k = j - 1];

            If [f[[i-1, j]] < f[[i-1, k]], k = j];
            If [j < ncols && f[[i-1, j+1]] < f[[i-1, k]], k = j + 1];

            f[[i, j]] = e[[i, j]] + f[[i-1, k]];
            t[[i, j]] = k - j;
        ];
    ];

    p = Table[1, {i, nrows}];
    For [j = 2, j <= ncols, j++, 
        i = p[[-1]];
        If [f[[nrows, i]] > f[[nrows, j]], 
            p[[-1]] = j;
        ];
    ];
    For [i = nrows - 1, i >= 1, i--, 
        j = p[[i+1]];
        p[[i]] = j + t[[i+1, j]];
    ];

    p
];
```

The computation complexity is only $O(MN)$. However, when I apply this function to a $900 \times 600$ matrix, it takes about 6 seconds to finish the computation.

Is my coding style wrong? Can my code be optimized such that it runs more quickly? Thank you.

Comment: This reminds me of Problem #81 of project euler. If you code in this style, why not use C/C++? Besides, try compiling your program. I think both the ways can boost its speed.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: See [Functional Paradigm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html)

Comment: Can you supply us with either your list for `e` or a function to generate the list so we can replicate your results and use them as a baseline?

Comment: My function to generate `e` is `e = Norm[#]& /@ #& /@ ImageData@ImageConvolve[img, {{1,1,1},{1,-8,1},{1,1,1}}]`, where `img` is a 900x600 image.

Comment: The "optimal" way to do this is using built-in capabilities of *Mathematica*. - a 1000X1000 test using `FindShortestPath` gets the result in a couple of seconds on an old netbook...

Comment: @rasher This is a graphics, not a graph. To build a graph from the picture to run FindShortestPath is complicated.

Comment: @Purboo: Nowhere in your OP is "picture" mentioned, simply "... matrix with non-negative values...", so comment stands. Building graph is trivial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my functional variant of your code:

```
findSeam2[e_List] := 
  Module[{f = FoldList[MinFilter[#1, 1] + #2 &, First[e], Rest[e]]},
   Reverse@
    FoldList[#1 + 
       First@Ordering[#2[[Max[1, #1 - 1] ;; 
            Min[Length[#2], #1 + 1]]]] - 1 - If[#1 == 1, 0, 1] &, 
     First@Ordering[Last[f], 1], Reverse@Most[f]]];
```

And my test case (inspired by [seam carving](http://perso.crans.org/frenoy/matlab2012/seamcarving.pdf)).

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
data = ImageData[GradientFilter[img, 1]];
AbsoluteTiming[seam = findSeam[data];]
Show[img, Graphics[{Red, Line[Flatten /@ MapIndexed[List, seam]]}]]
AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[seam2 = findSeam2[data];, 5]]
Show[img, Graphics[{Blue, Line[Flatten /@ MapIndexed[List, seam2]]}]]
seam == seam2
```

[image]

On my computer the timings are 2.4 and 0.07 seconds, respectively.

Note that by `Compile`ing your function, the timing is even better:

```
findSeam3 = 
 Compile[{{e, _Real, 2}}, 
  Module[ ...
   f = Table[0., {i, nrows}, {j, ncols}];
   ...
  ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

I only changed the initializer for `f` to use `0.`, so that the compiler is expecting floating-point values.  The timing for this test case is only 0.01 seconds!

Comment: That's nice. +1

Comment: If anyone knows of a better way to write `#2[[Max[1, #1 - 1] ;; Min[Length[#2], #1 + 1]]]`, let me know... I sometimes wish there was a function like `Take` or `Part` that automatically truncated out-of-range numbers.

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to learn "Compile" first.

Comment: Sometimes it is not easy to write code using functions like Apply, Map and Thread. In this case, is "Compile" the only way to accelerate the speed?

Comment: @Purboo "I think I need to learn `Compile` first." - Before that, I suggest you to read the last paragraph of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46160/1871). "Sometimes it is not easy to write code using functions like Apply, Map and Thread. " - Yeah, sometimes, but quite rare in my opinion, in most cases, it's just because you're not familiar enough with the coding style of _Mathematica_.

Comment: @xzczd Oh, I see. I will exercise more to get familiar with it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Purboo I don't think you need to "learn `Compile`," by writing in a C-like style you're already to be compiled to C.  However, you don't usually need to go to `Compile` if you get the hang of the functional programming style.

Comment: @2012rcampion Finally I digest your code. I can see the beauty behind FoldList :)

Comment: @2012rcampion it isn't shorter, but there's `Clip`, e.g. `Span @@ Clip[{#1 - 1, #1 + 1}, {1, Length@#2}]`, which reads a bit cleaner.

Comment: @rcollyer I do like `Clip` a heck of a lot better than `Max` and `Min`.  It's too bad `Clip` doesn't thread over `Span`.

Comment: @2012rcampion I agree, hence the need for `Apply` (`@@`).

Comment: Although, I would probably offload it into a separate function, e.g. 
`spanClip[s : Span[1, All, ___], max_] := s
spanClip[Span[a_, All, k___], max_] := 
 Span[Clip[a, {1, max}], All, k]
spanClip[Span[1, b_, k___], max_] := Span[1, Clip[b, {1, max}], k]
spanClip[Span[a_, b_, k___], max_] := 
 Span[##, k] & @@ Clip[{a, b}, {1, max}]` or something like that.