# How to speed up auxilary DoolittleDecomposite function?

Tags: programming, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

The [Doolittle Decomposition algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Doolittle_algorithm) as below:
$$A=LU$$
where

$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots a_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}
L=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots 0\\
l_{21} & 1 & \cdots 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
l_{n1} & l_{n2} & \cdots 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
$
U=\begin{pmatrix}
u_{11} & u_{12} & \cdots u_{1n}\\
0 & u_{12} & \cdots u_{12}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots u_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

And

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_{kj}=a_{kj}-\sum_{m=1}^{k-1}l_{km}u_{mj} && (j=k,k+1,\cdots,n)\\
l_{ik}=1/u_{kk} (a_{ik}-\sum_{m=1}^{k-1}l_{im}u_{mk}) && (i=k+1,k+2,\cdots,n)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Where, $k=1,2,\cdots,n$

#### Implementation

```
oneStep[mat_?MatrixQ, {intermediate_, index_}] :=
 Module[{temp = intermediate, k = index, row},
  row = Length@mat;
  Table[
   temp[[k, j]] =
    mat[[k, j]] - Sum[temp[[k, m]] temp[[m, j]], {m, 1, k - 1}], {j, k, row}];
  Table[
   temp[[i, k]] =
    1/temp[[k, k]] (mat[[i, k]] - 
   Sum[temp[[i, m]] temp[[m, k]], {m, 1, k - 1}]), {i, k + 1, row}];
 {temp, k+1}
]
 (*==============================*)

doolittleDecomposite[mat_?MatrixQ] :=
 Module[{intermediate, row},
  intermediate = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions@mat];
  row = Length@mat;
  First@
   Nest[oneStep[mat, #] &, {intermediate, 1}, row]
]
```

#### Test

```
test={{1, 6, 1, 9}, {4, 4, 9, 7}, {10, 4, 10, 2}, {10, 3, 10, 2}};
doolittleDecomposite[test]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 6 & 1 & 9 \\
>  4 & -20 & 5 & -29 \\
>  10 & \frac{14}{5} & -14 & -\frac{34}{5} \\
>  10 & \frac{57}{20} & \frac{57}{56} & \frac{11}{7} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Namely,

$L=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 10 & \frac{14}{5} & 1 & 0 \\
 10 & \frac{57}{20} & \frac{57}{56} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
U=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 6 & 1 & 9 \\
 0 & -20 & 5 & -29 \\
 0 & 0 & -14 & -\frac{34}{5} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{11}{7} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

#### Performance testing

```
SeedRandom[1234];
testReal = RandomReal[{1., 100.}, {200, 200}];
doolittleDecomposite[testReal]; // AbsoluteTiming
LUDecomposition[testReal]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {6.102349, Null}
> {0.034002, Null}  (*big performance difference*)
> ```

```
SeedRandom[12]
testInteger = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {100, 100}];
doolittleDecomposite[testInteger]; // AbsoluteTiming
LUDecomposition[testInteger]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {6.173353, Null}
> {4.481256, Null}  (*a bit difference*)
> ```

#### Question

- Is it possible to speed up my implementation code?
- Could someone give me some `hints`(like how to organize the data) to implement this algorithm elegantly in *Mathematica*?Namely, I think my method is not good:)

Comment: Might try changing the sums to dot products. Also `Table` probably should be `Do`. For the machine real case you could run it through `Compile`.

Comment: The `oneStep` function  that I implemented is C-style(like procedural paradigm) . So my main difficult is `how to store and organize the intermediate result in right way` if I'd like to implement this algorithm with functional or rule-based paradigm.

Comment: Might want to check the notebook [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/288/Numerics.nb?file_id=2196). Dated a bit but still quite relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: I've just seen this. I believe you know, but just to remind, algorithms of this sort are usually made with a pivoting strategy in place (e.g. partial, total, or rook); otherwise, there are a lot of nonsingular matrices that do not have a decomposition.

Comment: @J.M. I cannot understand the conception of **pivoting strategy**. Could you give a explonation about it? Or you give a **counter example** that is non-singular , but does not have a decomposition by the algorithm of mine

Comment: With respect to the counterexample, try `Reverse[IdentityMatrix[4]]`. As for pivoting: did you notice the difference between your method and `LUDecomposition[]`? The latter one outputs a *permutation list*, which encodes the (partial) pivoting (interchanges of rows) done in the course of decomposing the matrix. Any robust implementation has to have a pivoting strategy like that.

Comment: @J.M. You are right, `Reverse[IdentityMatrix[4]] // doolittleDecomposite2` in this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/78998/revisions) gives the `Power::infy` error information. And I noticed the difference that  `LUDecomposition` returns a list of three elements.

Comment: @J.M. In addition, the formula that I used to implement the`LU` decomposition came from my textbook of **Numerical Analysis**.

Comment: ...and that book ought to have mentioned permutations/pivoting somewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's pretty clear that the complexity of this function is $\text{O}(n^3)$, since we're iterating over each element of a matrix (a factor of $n^2$) and taking a sum at each one (an additional factor of $n$).  However, we can't really do anything to reduce the complexity; LU decomposition has the same complexity as matrix multiplication.  Although algorithms faster than $\text{O}(n^3)$ [do exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) I do not think they are used in practice.

---

The upshot of all this is that if we really want to increase our speed, we should `Compile` our function.  Here is [an algorithm in Fortran](http://www.engr.colostate.edu/%7Ethompson/hPage/CourseMat/Tutorials/CompMethods/doolittle.pdf) that is in-place; that is, it doesn't use any extra memory (although we do need to copy the matrix once so that we can 'edit' it).  We can write a `CompiledFunction` to implement this version of the algorithm:

```
doolittleDecomposition = Compile[{{a, _Real, 2}},
  With[{n = Length[a]},
   Module[{t = a},
    Do[
     Do[
      Do[
        t[[i, j]] -= t[[i, k]] t[[k, j]];,
        {k, 1, i - 1}];,
      {j, i, n}];
     Do[
      Do[
       t[[j, i]] -= t[[j, k]] t[[k, i]];,
       {k, 1, i - 1}];
      t[[j, i]] /= t[[i, i]];,
      {j, i + 1, n}];,
     {i, 1, n}];
    t
    ]
   ],
  {{q, _Real}}
  , RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}]
```

We should double-check that our function doesn't call `MainEvaluate`, which is slow:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
doolittleDecomposition // CompilePrint
```

While doing this check I discovered that I originally wrote `t[j, i]` instead of `t[[j, i]]`, causing `MainEvaluate` to be called.  Always double-check!  In fact, let's now double-check that both algorithms give the same result:

```
testReal = RandomReal[1, {200, 200}];
d1 = doolittleDecomposite[testReal]; // AbsoluteTiming
d2 = doolittleDecomposition[testReal]; // AbsoluteTiming
d1 == d2
```

This also shows that the `Compile`d version is faster.

### Update: Refactoring the original code

If you think `Compile` is too drastic (or you don't have a working C compiler) there are some other changes we can make.

- Don't use an auxiliary or 'helper' function.  This will incur extra overhead that you don't need.  Unlike a compiled language where the compiler will essentially inline the function, Mathematica will be passing-by-value all of your matrices!
- Don't use `Nest`.  If we're getting rid of the helper function, `Nest` doesn't really make sense.  We can replace it with a `Do`-loop instead.  The `Do`-loop can 'automatically' increment `k`, instead of having to pass it (in a list!) to a function and have it returned (also in a list!!).  At this point we can rename `intermediate` to `temp`, consolidating two variables that really contain the same thing, and we also can lose the extra redefinition of `row` inside the loop.
- Use `Dot` instead of `Sum`.  In general, if there's a builtin function for something, that function is faster.  In this case you want to pairwise multiply two lists and take the sum of the resulting elements.  We usually call that a dot product.  Instead of looping `m`, we can use `Span` to extract a list using `Part`, and then `Dot` our two lists together.  **This is where most of the speedup comes from.**

At this point the code looks pretty much like the Fortran function, but with the inner loops handled by `Dot`:

```
doolittleDecomposite2[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
 Module[{temp = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions@mat], row = Length@mat},
  Do[
   Do[temp[[k, j]] =
     mat[[k, j]] - temp[[k, ;; k - 1]].temp[[;; k - 1, j]],
    {j, k, row}];
   Do[temp[[i, k]] =
     (mat[[i, k]] - temp[[i, ;; k - 1]].temp[[;; k - 1, k]]) / temp[[k, k]],
    {i, k + 1, row}];,
   {k, row}];
  temp
  ]
```

### Updated performance analysis

I ran another comparison, this time including `LUDecomposition`, just to see how well we did:

[image]

The first thing I noticed (even before I generated the plots) was that the original solution takes an unreasonably long time on matrices larger than around $n>250$ (I tried $n=400$ and let it run for at least an hour before aborting manually).  I suspect this has to do with memory bandwidth when passing `temp` into `Sum`.

The second think to notice is that `LUDecomposition` is *fast*.  Not only is it at least two orders of magnitude faster than mine, but below $n=1000$ it is almost instant (less than 10 ms).  The former is probably from using highly optimized libraries like the the [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl).  As for the latter, it's probably not a coincidence that the 'fast' runs all have memory usage below the size of my CPU cache (8MB):

[image]

The third thing to notice is that while all of our solutions are firmly $\text{O}(n^3)$ for large numbers, the native `LUDecomposition` is actually closer to $\text{O}(n^{2.4})$, meaning that there is probably a large $\text{O}(n^2)$ factor that the leading $n^3$ won't dominate until very large $n$.

Similarly, although the refactored version appears to be slightly better than $\text{O}(n^3)$, this is only because of all the overhead; as the vectors passed to `Dot` get larger, the $n^3$ term will eventually dominate.

Looking back at the memory usage plot, we can see that the original function doesn't use much more memory than mine.  All are asymptotically $\text{O}(n^2)$.  The reason the original takes so long is because Mathematica is essentially pass-by-value, so it's making a huge `malloc` and `free` every time it calls the helper function.

The refactored version uses almost exactly the same amount of memory as my `Compile`d solution (excepting a small $\text{O}(n)$ contribution from the vectors and `Dot`) because we avoid all that argument-passing and copying.

As to why I'm using almost exactly 3× more memory than `LUDecomposition`, it's probably also due to pass-by-value semantics: Mathematica constructs a version of the matrix to pass to the `CompiledFunction`, which then makes it's own working copy, which is then copied again to produce the result.  As `LUDecomposition` is a native function, it can avoid all that.

Comment: @ShutaoTang does the update answer your question about "how to store and organize the intermediate result?"  (Namely, don't copy it around.)

Comment: You can use `Compile\`GetElement` to speed up `doolittleDecomposition` by a factor of 2. (See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61597/1871) for an example. )

Comment: +1Nice answer,thanks a lot. In fact, I'd like to implement this algorithm in `functional paradigm`(like `Nest`, because I think `functional paradigm` is more efficient) at the beginning. However, I didn't know how to organize the `intermediate result`(like $u_{11},u_{12} \cdots u_{1n}$). So I use the `Do`(I am always thinking it is not efficient in *Mathematica*) to implement it. In addition, @Daniel Lichtblau gave the suggestion(changing the `Sum` to dot products), but I forgot to use the *built-in* function`Span(;;)` . So your edit fo my original code is very elegant:)

Comment: @xzczd Interesting, why is that not the default behavior of `Compile`?

Comment: @ShutaoTang The Doolittle algorithm is essentially procedural: shoehorning it into a functional construct will not make it faster. The reason we advise a functional style most of the time is that builtins are usually faster; but there are no builtins that apply to this case.  I believe my testing shows that here, `Do` is faster than `Nest`.

Comment: @xzczd Actually I don't see a noticeable speedup from using `GetElement`... is there a way to inspect the generated `C` code to see if anything changed?

Comment: Maybe it's due to the compiler? I use _TDM-GCC 4.8.1_, with `"CompileOptions"->"-Ofast"`, and this is my implementation: `doolittleDecomposition2 = 
 With[{g = Compile\`GetElement}, 
  Compile[{{a, _Real, 2}}, 
   With[{n = Length[a]}, 
    Module[{t = a}, 
     Do[Do[Do[
         t[[i, j]] -= g[t, i, k] g[t, k, j];, {k, 1, i - 1}];, {j, i, 
        n}];
      Do[Do[t[[j, i]] -= g[t, j, k] g[t, k, i];, {k, 1, i - 1}];
       t[[j, i]] /= g[t, i, i];, {j, i + 1, n}];, {i, 1, n}];
     t]], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"]]`.

Comment: For the reason why `Compile\`GetElement` is fast, it's mentioned [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/824/1871) that it turns off the bound check.

Comment: Just to clarify, neither `LUDecomposition` nor underlying MKL library code use fast matrix multiplication methods (by "fast" I mean faster that O(n^3) e.g. Strassen).

Comment: @xzczd I thought `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` already disabled bounds checking.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for correcting me, I've fixed the offending statement

Comment: Well, I'm not that familiar with the internal mechanism, either, but the `Compile\`GetElement` trick does work, at least on my machine.

Comment: BTW, is it possible to `Compile` the `doolittleDecomposite2` function that you refactored? Thanks:)

Comment: @ShutaoTang Yes, you should just be able to wrap `Compile` around the whole thing.  (Note that you should use `Set` and not `SetDelayed`, or the function will be recompiled on every call.)  I suspect the generated code will be pretty much identical to my `Compile`d function.

Comment: I don't know why, the result of your function `doolittleDecomposite2` is different from that of the built-in function `LUDecomposition`:`A = {{2, 0, 1, 2}, {4, -3, -2, 2}, {2, 6, -5, 1}, {6, 3, -1, 2}}; 
doolittleDecomposite2[A]
LUDecomposition[A]`.

Comment: @Alittle LU decomposition is in general not unique, so if the built-in function uses a different algorithm it can yield a different result.

Answer (score 2):

The function `doolittleDecomposite2` refactored by @2012rcampion can use `Span(;;)` to avoid the inner `Do` loop

```
doolittle[mat_?MatrixQ] :=
 Module[
  {temp = ConstantArray[1, Dimensions@mat], row = Length@mat},
  Do[
   temp[[k, k ;; row]] =
    mat[[k, k ;; row]] - temp[[k, ;; k - 1]].temp[[;; k - 1, k ;; row]];
   temp[[k + 1 ;; row, k]] =
    (mat[[k + 1 ;; row, k]] - 
     temp[[k + 1 ;; row, ;; k - 1]].temp[[;; k - 1, k]])/temp[[k, k]];,
 {k, row}];
 temp
]
```

**Or**

```
LU[mat_] :=
 Module[{n, L, U},
  n = Length@mat;
  L = IdentityMatrix[n];
  U = mat;
  Do[
   L[[k ;; n, k]] = U[[k ;; n, k]]/U[[k, k]];
   U[[(k + 1) ;; n, k ;; n]] = 
    U[[(k + 1) ;; n, k ;; n]] - L[[(k + 1) ;; n, {k}]].U[[{k}, k ;; n]];
  , {k, 1, n - 1}];
 {L, U}
]

(*=========================*)
mat = RandomInteger[10, {5, 5}]
LUDecomposition@mat
```

> $
> \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \frac{4}{7} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & -\frac{14}{5} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & -\frac{49}{20} & \frac{219}{176} & 1 & 0 \\
>  \frac{5}{7} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{5}{88} & -\frac{270}{1303} & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  7 & 9 & 6 & 0 & 8 \\
>  0 & \frac{20}{7} & -\frac{17}{7} & 10 & -\frac{25}{7} \\
>  0 & 0 & -\frac{44}{5} & 34 & -14 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1303}{88} & \frac{939}{88} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{4552}{1303} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: "can use `Span` (`;;`)" - and thus, *Mathematica* has caught up to MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `LUDecomposition` is builtin.

```
LUDecomposition[{{1, 6, 1, 9}, {4, 4, 9, 7}, {10, 4, 10, 2}, {10, 3, 10, 2}}]

{{{1, 6, 1, 9}, {4, -20, 5, -29}, {10, 14/5, -14, -(34/5)}, {10, 57/20, 57/56, 11/7}}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, 1}
```

Comment: The OP is aware of this, given he compares the times obtained with the builtin.