# LU factorization

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Basically what I need to do is this:

Write an algorithm that finds the LU factorization of the following matrix. The algorithm should perform the necessary elementary row operations to reduce A to U, and store the various multipliers in each step.  The output of the program should be two matrices: L and U.

```
A={{3,1,2}{6,3,4},{3,1,5}}
```

I can't use any of the built in code for LU or partial pivoting or any of that stuff that will finish it off with one function.  I just need a little help getting started being as how I'm still new to programming.  I know how I would do it all manually but writing the code for a general algorithm is eluding me.  I'll obviously need to use for loops to test if

```
A[[2,1]]=0, A[[3,1]]=0
```

And that is about as far as I am.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Dupe?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78700)

Comment: In any case, you'll want to look up Golub and Van Loan; there's a nice discussion there on how to implement this.

Comment: Problems with your matrix?  Check using PseudoInverse[{{3, 1, 2} {6, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 5}}]

Comment: @thils, for somebody just starting to understand Gaussian elimination, SVD is like handing a toddler a mountain bike.

Comment: @JM What I am trying to convey is that LU factorization will run into problems for matrices with no inverse or near singular matrices.

Comment: @thils, yes, but that's something usually discussed *after* a full understanding of GE. Baby steps, and all that.

Comment: *Must* you write the code? I ask because: (i) *Mathematica* already has a built-in function `LUDecomposition`; and (ii) such code is already out there on the web, and a search will lead you to it (forget that if this is a homework assignment!).

Comment: @murray  The matrix must be non-singular for built-in function to work.