# How to force evaluation of an expression with Part left unnevaluated?

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation, hold

My goal is to minimize a real valued multi-variable function `averageFreeEnergyDensity`. The function accepts an integer argument `n`, a set of real parameters `j,d,a,h,dx` and two real matrices `th,ph`. I want to find matrices `th,ph` which minimize the function. `FindMinimum` minimizes the function well enough but it is too slow at the moment. I am trying to compile the function to accelerate `FindMinimum`. If I compile the function for arbitrary `n` it is at least an order of magnitude more slow than if I make a set of functions each of which is defined for a particular `n`. My current fastest solution is

```
averageFreeEnergyDensityCompiled["square",n_]:=
 averageFreeEnergyDensityCompiled["square", n]= 
  Compile[{{j, _Real}, {d, _Real}, {a, _Real}, {h, _Real}, {dx,
_Real}, {th, _Real, 2}, {ph, _Real, 2}}, Evaluate[
    (*apply boundary conditions*)
    s[i1_, i2_] := Which[
      i1 == n + 1 && i2 == n + 1, s[1, 1],
      i1 == n + 1, s[1, i2],
      i2 == n + 1, s[i1, 1],
      True, {Cos[ph[[i1, i2]]] Sin[th[[i1, i2]]], 
       Sin[ph[[i1, i2]]] Sin[th[[i1, i2]]], Cos[th[[i1, i2]]]}
      ];
    (*define finite difference functions*)
    dsdx[i1_, i2_] := (s[i1 + 1, i2] - s[i1, i2])/dx;
    dsdy[i1_, i2_] := (s[i1, i2 + 1] - s[i1, i2])/dx;
    (*return average free energy density function*)
    Sum[j (dsdx[i1, i2].dsdx[i1, i2] + dsdy[i1, i2].dsdy[i1, i2]) + 
       a s[i1, i2][[3]]^2 - h s[i1, i2][[3]], {i1, 1, n}, {i2, 1, n}]/
     n^2
    ]]
```

I need to delay evaluation because the expression being compiled can only be evaluated for particular `n`. I store the function because I will evaluate it for many values of `j,d,a,h,dx`. This solution is fast but it throws an error the first time the function is evaluated

```
Block[{n = 100}, 
 AbsoluteTiming[
  averageFreeEnergyDensityCompiled["square", n][1, 1, 1, 0, 0.1, 
   Array[0 &, {n, n}], RandomReal[2 Pi, {n, n}]]]]
Part::partd: Part specification ph$[[2,1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
Part::partd: Part specification th$[[2,1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
Part::partd: Part specification ph$[[2,1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
General::stop: Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

After several attempts to evaluate the `Part` function Mathematica gives up and evaluates the expression ignoring `Part`. The final expression can then be compiled. I want to manually tell Mathematica to ignore `Part`. I have tried using `Inactive,Activate` but this slows down the final compiled function by orders of magnitude. I would ideally give an option to `Evaluate` like `Evaluate["insert expression here",Holding->Part]` but `Evaluate` has no options that I know of.

Note: The boundary condition I have used here is simple and can be taken out of compile, but I will be using more complicated boundary conditions once I solve this problem. I do not need to use finite difference steps of order greater than 1. I will also be using this code on a triangular grid which will further change the finite difference.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) will work for you here:

```
mem : averageFreeEnergyDensityCompiled["square", n_] := mem =
  Block[{Part},
   Compile[{{j, _Real}, {d, _Real}, {a, _Real}, {h, _Real}, {dx, _Real}, {th, _Real, 
      2}, {ph, _Real, 2}}, 
    Evaluate[(*apply boundary conditions*)
     s[i1_, i2_] := 
      Which[i1 == n + 1 && i2 == n + 1, s[1, 1], i1 == n + 1, s[1, i2], i2 == n + 1, 
       s[i1, 1], True, {Cos[ph[[i1, i2]]] Sin[th[[i1, i2]]], 
        Sin[ph[[i1, i2]]] Sin[th[[i1, i2]]], Cos[th[[i1, i2]]]}];
     (*define finite difference functions*)
     dsdx[i1_, i2_] := (s[i1 + 1, i2] - s[i1, i2])/dx;
     dsdy[i1_, i2_] := (s[i1, i2 + 1] - s[i1, i2])/dx;
     (*return average free energy density function*)
     Sum[j (dsdx[i1, i2].dsdx[i1, i2] + dsdy[i1, i2].dsdy[i1, i2]) + a s[i1, i2][[3]]^2 - 
        h s[i1, i2][[3]], {i1, 1, n}, {i2, 1, n}]/n^2]]
  ]
```

However I believe [`` Compile`GetElement ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/824/121) will also work and perform better too.  Search for "GetElement" (on this site) for more information.

```
mem : averageFreeEnergyDensityCompiled["square", n_] := mem =
  With[{Part = Compile`GetElement},
   Compile[{{j, _Real}, {d, _Real}, {a, _Real}, {h, _Real}, {dx, _Real}, {th, _Real, 
      2}, {ph, _Real, 2}}, 
    Evaluate[(*apply boundary conditions*)
     s[i1_, i2_] := 
      Which[i1 == n + 1 && i2 == n + 1, s[1, 1], i1 == n + 1, s[1, i2], i2 == n + 1, 
       s[i1, 1], True, {Cos[ph[[i1, i2]]] Sin[th[[i1, i2]]], 
        Sin[ph[[i1, i2]]] Sin[th[[i1, i2]]], Cos[th[[i1, i2]]]}];
     (*define finite difference functions*)
     dsdx[i1_, i2_] := (s[i1 + 1, i2] - s[i1, i2])/dx;
     dsdy[i1_, i2_] := (s[i1, i2 + 1] - s[i1, i2])/dx;
     (*return average free energy density function*)
     Sum[j (dsdx[i1, i2].dsdx[i1, i2] + dsdy[i1, i2].dsdy[i1, i2]) + a s[i1, i2][[3]]^2 - 
        h s[i1, i2][[3]], {i1, 1, n}, {i2, 1, n}]/n^2]]
  ]
```

(See the note at the bottom of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/121) for explanation of the `mem` thing.)

Comment: I see no speed improvements with Compile`GetElement but it is more aesthetically pleasing for me.

There is still an error when using compiled functions in FindMinimum; it attempts to evaluate the function symbolically. [The solution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationSymbolicEvaluation.html) to this problem is to define a function which is only defined for numeric arguments.