# How to compile procedural program effectively

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

Consider these four function in different form:

```
f1[ls1_] := Append[Rest@ls1, 0.] + Prepend[Most@ls1, 0.]

f2 = Compile[{{ls1, _Real, 1}}, 
   Append[Rest@ls1, 0.] + Prepend[Most@ls1, 0.], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];

f3[ls_] := Module[{n = Length@ls, tp = ls},
  tp[[1]] = ls[[2]];
  tp[[n]] = ls[[n - 1]];
  Do[
   tp[[i]] = ls[[i - 1]] + ls[[i + 1]], {i, 2, n - 1}
   ];
  tp]

f4 = Compile[{{ls, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{n = Length@ls, tp = ls},
    tp[[1]] = ls[[2]];
    tp[[n]] = ls[[n - 1]];
    Do[
     tp[[i]] = ls[[i - 1]] + ls[[i + 1]], {i, 2, n - 1}
     ];
    tp], CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

Comparing their performance, we can see that the functional version `f1` and `f2` have about the same performance, but the compiled procedural version `f4` is about 2X slower.

```
ls = Sin /@ (Range[1, 2000]/2000.);

AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[Do[f1[ls];, {20000}], 5]]
AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[Do[f2[ls];, {20000}], 5]]
AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[Do[f3[ls];, {20000}], 5]]
AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[Do[f4[ls];, {20000}], 5]]

(*{0.976474,Null}*)
(*{0.784508,Null}*)
(*{5.000856,$Aborted}*)
(*{1.595374,Null}*)
```

However, if we test the procedural version in Fortran (code at the end), it runs about 4X faster than `f2`.

```
xslittlegrass$ ifort -r8 -O0 test.f90
    xslittlegrass$ ./a.out
      0.232574000000000
xslittlegrass$
```

**Questions:**

1. Why `f4` is about 2X slower than `f1` and `f2`?
2. Why `f4` is about 7X slower than the Fortran version?
3. Can we make a compiled version that has comparable performance to the Fortran version?
4. I thought that a procedural function compiled to C is comparable in performance compared to procedural functions written in C. But this example seems to disagree with it. So in general how large is the gap of the performance between these two?

---

test.f90

```
program main
implicit none

integer,parameter :: N0 = 2000
integer i,j
real(kind=8) :: list(N0), result(N0),start,finish

do i = 1, N0
    list(i) = sin(i/real(N0))
end do


call CPU_TIME(start)

do j = 1, 20000
    result(1) = list(2)
    result(N0) = list(N0-1)
    do i=2,N0-1
        result(i) = list(i+1) + list(i-1)
    end do
end do

call CPU_TIME(finish)

write(*,*) finish-start

end program
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `CompilePrint` output for those compiled functions? Maybe something in the way they are translated to compiled code might explain the difference. Also Leonid has a good set of pointers on [How to compile effectively](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1816/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB one looks procedural (obviously!) while the other uses compiled implementations of `Inset` and `Drop`.

Comment: Are you sure that mma is only 7x slower than fortran? Which fortran compiler do you use? If you use intel cpu, you should choose intel fortran, you will be astonished by the result. On my computer, f4 takes 1.43sec, while your fortran code if compiled with gfortran, takes 0.2sec, But if compiled with ifort, only 0.0268sec !!!!! Be caution, you should add an output code to get the real time, or ifort is smart enough to know that you didn't output anything, so it will just doesn't do anything.

Comment: and I forgot to put RuntimeOption->"Speed" timing, with this option, f4 takes 0.393sec

Comment: @matheorem Thanks for the test. I was using the intel compiler, but with optimization turned off.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Why turn off the optimization?

Comment: @matheorem As you have discovered, sometimes the compiler is smart enough to skip some computations. I don't want that to happen.

Comment: @xslittlegrass well, you just have to tell it. Don't be that lazy, to give the final result : )

Comment: @xslittlegrass so finally, have you figured out have to achieve performance to be comparable to fortran in mma?

Comment: @matheorem No. I'm not sure whether that's possible or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an answer to Q1 and partly Q4, really. I can't test your Fortran version at the moment, but it would be an interesting comparison.

You can improve the performance of `f4` compared to `f1` and `f2` by setting [`RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuntimeOptions.html). Clearly the change in runtime settings (mainly `"CatchMachineIntegerOverflow"` it seems...) from the defaults has a different effect on the two functions.

For instance:

```
f2 = Compile[{{ls1, _Real, 1}}, 
   Append[Rest@ls1, 0.] + Prepend[Most@ls1, 0.], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

f4 = Compile[{{ls, _Real, 1}}, 
   Module[{n = Length@ls, tp = ls}, tp[[1]] = ls[[2]];
    tp[[n]] = ls[[n - 1]];
    Do[tp[[i]] = ls[[i - 1]] + ls[[i + 1]], {i, 2, n - 1}];
    tp], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[Do[f2[ls];, {20000}], 5]]
(* 0.152 seconds *)

AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[Do[f4[ls];, {20000}], 5]]
(* 0.127 seconds *)
```

Comment: Hi, blochwave, if you are interested in fortran timing, see my comment to xslittlegrass

Comment: basically, if compiled with ifort on intel cpu, even RuntimeOptions->"Speed" is still more than 10x slower than fortran

Answer (score 6):

In the fortran version, you have the large loop within the executable and you call the executable only once. Also quite important: You allocate memory for `result` only once. In order to make the benchmark fair, you should compare to something like

```
f5 = Compile[{{ls, _Real, 1}},
  Module[{n = Length@ls, tp},
    tp = Table[0., {Length[ls]}];
    Do[
     tp[[1]] = ls[[2]];
     tp[[n]] = ls[[n - 1]];
     Do[tp[[i]] = ls[[i - 1]] + ls[[i + 1]], {i, 2, n - 1}];
     , {20000}];
    tp],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];
```

On my machine, calling `f5[ls]` takes about 0.067 s while `Do[f4[ls];, {20000}]` needs about 0.58 s. The fortran variant (see below) compiled with `gfortran -o bla test2.f90 -O3` needs about 0.012 s. Moreover, the call `f6[ls]` with the function defined below needs only 0.034 seconds which is not too far away from the fortran timing.

```
f6 = Compile[{{ls, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{n = Length@ls, tp},
    tp = Table[0., {n}];
    Do[
     tp[[1]] = Compile`GetElement[ls, 2];
     tp[[n]] = Compile`GetElement[ls, n - 1];
     Do[
      tp[[i]] = Compile`GetElement[ls, i - 1] + Compile`GetElement[ls, i + 1],
      {i, 2, n - 1}], 
    {20000}];
    tp],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

test2.f90

```
program main
implicit none
integer,parameter :: N0 = 2000
integer i,j
real (kind=8) :: list(N0), result(N0),start,finish
do i = 1, N0
    list(i) = sin(i/real(N0))
end do
call CPU_TIME(start)
do j = 1, 20000
    result(1) = list(2)
    result(N0) = list(N0-1)
    do i=2,N0-1
        result(i) = list(i+1) + list(i-1)
    end do
end do
call CPU_TIME(finish)
write(*,*) result
write(*,*) finish-start
end program
```

PS.: I have still not used parallelization, here. Even with the dullest way to do that within Mathematica, I get (on a Quad Core CPU):

```
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelDo[f6[ls], {i, 1, $KernelCount}]][[1]]/($KernelCount)
(* 0.0125135 *)
```

and by even increasing the number of jobs:

```
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelDo[f6[ls], {i, 1, $KernelCount 10}]][[ 1]]/($KernelCount 10)
(* 0.00855335 *)
```

Admittedly, it is not exactly fair to compare this to the unparallelized fortran code. I added this only to show another possibility to speed up the Mathematica code.